# Is there a word for the single letter contractions commonly used in store names?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, contractions

Is there a term for the single-letter contractions as used in the following examples?

- Toys 'r' us
- Stop 'n' go

(Note: Trademarks above have been corrected for proper grammar.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*’n’* is a conjunction with a listed definition of “and” given in various dictionaries, such as [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%27n%27) and [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/%27n%27).

The letter R in the name *Toys “R” Us* is given with double quotation marks (not apostrophes) [on their web site](http://www.toysrusinc.com/about-us/). Their logo uses a backwards-facing letter R. Presumably the “misspelling” of the word *are* combined with reversed letter is intended to make it seem as though a child produced the logo. Misspelling homophones (the letter R and the word *are* are both pronounced the same) and producing letters which are a mirror image of the correct letter are common errors of children who are just learning to write.

The first example I can comfortably just describe as a *contraction*. The Random House dictionary calls it a “Pronunciation Spelling”. The R in *Toys “R” Us* is not really the same thing and is better described as an *intentional error*.

Comment: I'd say that using wacky spellings is mostly a way to be able to make a trademark out of what is otherwise just a three word expression.